# how to Join array with string in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables:

`Books` with column `tag_ids` (Array)

`Tags` with column `tag_id` (Varchar)

I have a visualisation tool that need to join these tables together. The only thing that I can control over is the join condition.
the problem is that I can't find a way to make this join work.

this is what I tried:

```
FROM "PUBLIC"."BOOKS"
LEFT JOIN "PUBLIC"."TAGS" ON (  "tag_ids" =  TO_ARRAY("tag_id"))
```

This works only on array with one element. It will not work for cases like:

tag_ids =

```
[
  "211d1383-13a6-4bef-85d1-bf5eda11c8a7",
  "2f6c332e-4726-4425-b364-e668e0f56582"
]
```

tag_id =

```
 ["211d1383-13a6-4bef-85d1-bf5eda11c8a7"]
```

Tried to do:

```
FROM "PUBLIC"."BOOKS"
LEFT JOIN "PUBLIC"."TAGS" ON ( ARRAYS_OVERLAP ("tag_ids" ,  TO_ARRAY("tag_id")) = TRUE ) )
```

I don't know if this works but it does certisian product and takes 15+ to run so I can't use this anyway.

What I'm looking for is basically to ask

```
if tag_id exist in tag_ids
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the `array_contains` function.

```
FROM "PUBLIC"."BOOKS"
LEFT JOIN "PUBLIC"."TAGS" ON (array_contains(tag_id, tag_ids))
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html).

Comment: Check the plan... this may turn into a cartesian product with a filter.

Answer (score 6):

Flatten the array and `join`:

```
select b.*, t.*
from public.books b cross join
     table(flatten(b.tags)) bt join
     tags t
     on bt.tags = t.tag_id;
```

Comment: For my query, this approach is FAR more efficient.